# Real part of complex root of $X^5-X-k^5+k+1$ is $\frac{1}{23k}$ away from any integer ($k\geq 2$)

Tags: diophantine-approximation

Let $k\geq 2$ be an integer. The polynomial $P_k=X^5-X-k^5+k+1$ is easily
seen to have exactly one real root and two pair of conjugate non-real roots. Is it true
that if $\alpha_k + i \beta_k$ any non-real root of $P_k$, then $\lbrace \lbrace \alpha_k \rbrace \rbrace \geq \frac{1}{23k}$, where $\lbrace \lbrace \rbrace \rbrace$ denotes distance to the nearest integer ? I have checked this for $2 \leq k \leq 10^4$.

My thoughts : $\alpha_k$'s minimal polynomial can be shown to be of degree $10$, so Liouville's approximation theorem would suggest that $\lbrace \lbrace \alpha_k \rbrace \rbrace \geq \frac{C}{k^{10}}$ which is much weaker.

Motivation :  I noticed that the real root of $P_k$ is very close to its nearest integer while the real parts of the other roots are comparatively much farther. If quantified successfully, this would yield a proof of the irreducibility of $P_k$ over the rationals.

Comment: What's the source of the problem if you don't mind me asking ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon There is no particular source except for the context that I explained in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

*Not a full solution, but for large $k$ this should explain it.*

Let $X = r e^{i \phi}$. Then 
$$
P_k=r^5 e^{5 i  \phi}-r e^{i \phi}- k^5+k+1 
$$
Let $a = r^{-4}$.Then
$$
P_k=r^5 (e^{5 i  \phi}-a e^{i \phi})- k^5+k+1 
$$
For the roots, the imaginary part of this has to vanish, so we have
$$
0 = \sin(5 \phi)-a \sin(\phi)
$$
Using the trig. identity $\sin(5 \phi) = \sin(\phi) (16\cos^4(\phi) - 12\cos^2(\phi) + 1)$ this gives
$$
0 = 16\cos^4(\phi) - 12\cos^2(\phi) + 1 -a 
$$
Again, let $y = \cos^2(\phi)$, reducing this to 
$$
0 = 16 y^2 - 12 y + 1 -a 
$$
This gives
$$
y = \cos^2(\phi) = \frac{3\pm \sqrt{4a + 5}}{8}
$$

Turning now to the real part of the root, we have

$$
0 =r^5 (\cos(5 \phi)-a \cos(\phi))- k^5+k+1 
$$

With another trig. identity, 
$$\cos(5 \phi) = \cos(\phi) (16\cos^4(\phi) - 20\cos^2(\phi) + 5)
$$
we have, using results from above,
$$
0 =r^5 \cos(\phi) (16\cos^4(\phi) - 20\cos^2(\phi) + 5 -a)- k^5+k+1 \\
= r^5 \cos(\phi) (16y^2 - 20y + 5 -a)- k^5+k+1 \\
=r^5 \cos(\phi) ( - 8y + 4 )- k^5+k+1 \\
=r^5 \cos(\phi) ( 1\pm \sqrt{4a + 5})- k^5+k+1 
$$

But also 
$$
0 =r^5 \cos(\phi) ( - 8y + 4 )- k^5+k+1 \\
= 4 r^5 \cos(\phi) (1 - 2 \cos^2(\phi))- k^5+k+1 \\
= - 4 r^5 \cos(\phi) \cos(2 \phi)- k^5+k+1 \\
$$
and from above
$$
 - 4 \cos(2 \phi) = 1\pm \sqrt{5 + 4/r^4}
$$

For very large $k$, we have also very large $r$, which gives approximately
$$
 - 4 \cos(2 \phi) = 1\pm \sqrt{5} \rightarrow \phi = \pm \frac{2 \pi}{5}
$$
So $- 4  \cos(\phi) \cos(2 \phi) = 1$ and 
$$
0 = r^5 - k^5+k+1 \rightarrow r =  k
$$
Hence 
$$
a_k = r \cos(\phi) = \frac{k}{4} (\sqrt5 -1)
$$
 is the real part of the root for very large $k$. Now, for large $k$,  we have that $a_k$ will not be close enough ($< 1/(23 k)$) to any integer, say $n$, since this would approximately require $(4 n +k)^2 = 5 k^2 $.

The same can be done for the other solution pair.

It remains to be estimated how large $k$ has to become such that  the derived bounds hold. For smaller $k$, then, validity can be shown manually.

Comment: Unfortunately, $\cos(\phi)$ is irrational, so the distribution of the fractional part of $k\cos(\phi)$ is quite erratic a priori. To make your idea work, one would need to know more about Diphantine approximations of $\cos(\phi)$.